# Mustache only printing out one object of the array instead of all the objects of the array

Tags: jquery, mustache

I am new to Mustache and templating. I am trying to iterate through my object of arrays and display them on the dom using mustache and ajax. As of now the content is not being passed to the content.

Here is my script:

```
var ajax = function(){
        alert('crackers');
        var request1 = $.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.js",
            dataType:'json',
        }).then(function(response){
                var data = response.projects;
                var template = $('#projects_tmp').html();
                var project = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                return project;
        });
        var request2 = $.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.js",
            dataType:'json',
        }).then(function(response){
            var data = response.projects;
            var template = $('#projectHeader_tmp').html();
            var projectHeader = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            //console.log(projectHeader);
            return projectHeader;
        });

        $.when(request1, request2).then(function(t,r) {
           $('.projects').html(t).prepend(r);
        });
    }


    $("#header").on('click', ajax);

}());
```

I tried using the {{#projects}}[template]{{/projects}} but nothing shows up. if i remove the tags it works but only shows one item of the template when their should be 14.
here is my template:

```
<script id="projects_tmp" type="text/template">
            <div class='small-6 medium-3 columns left thumb {{{genre}}}'>
                <div class='project'><figure><img src='{{{largePic}}}' alt='' />
                <figcaption class='caption'><span>{{genre}}</span></figcaption class='caption'></figure></div>
               </div >
            </div >
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer:

```
    var ajax = function(){
        var request1 = $.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.js",
            dataType:'json',
        }).then(function(response){
            var data = response.projects;
            var template = $('#projects_tmp').html();
            var projects;
            $.each(data, function(key,val){
                 projects += Mustache.to_html(template, val);
                return projects;
            });
            var project = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            return projects;
        });

        var request2 = $.ajax({
                url: "js/projects.js",
                dataType:'json',
            }).then(function(response){
                var template = $('#projectHeader_tmp').html();
                var projectHeader = Mustache.to_html(template);
                return projectHeader;
            });

        $.when(request1, request2).then(function(t,r) {
           $('.projects').html(t).prepend(r);
        });
    }

    $("#header").on('click', ajax);
```